# db.createUser() stalls out

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to create a user in a mongoDB database, but every time I enter the command it just outputs `...` and stalls out.

example:

```
> db.createUser({user: "myUser", pwd: "myPassword", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myDB" } ])
> ...
```

Eventually, after a few minutes of waiting, I just hit enter a couple of times and it cancels the command.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a final closing `}`

```
db.createUser({user: "myUser", pwd: "myPassword", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myDB" } ]})
                                                                                            ^^^^
```

Easier to see with spacing:

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "myUser", 
        pwd: "myPassword", 
        roles: [ 
            { 
                role: "readWrite", 
                db: "myDB" 
            } 
        ]
    }
 )
```

Comment: Thanks! Really wish it would throw a syntax error for that.